# Change the zoom Type dynamically?

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the zoom-type from "x" to "xy" without creating new instance,
I want do do it like update() method they have..
located in `myChart.options.chart.zoomType`

Comment: You can't. So you have to recreate the chart.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First Prepare a string for the chart to display

**Clone Series To Redraw as highcharts set it null after draw.**

```
var seriesClone=[{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,9,10,14]
   }]
```

**Series Options To SET**

```
   var chartOptions={   

    chart: {
        renderTo:'container',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,9,10,14]
    }]
                 }

 var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(chartOptions);
```

And When you  want to change the value of ZoomType redeclare the chart like this

```
   chartOptions.chart.zoomType='y';
   chartOptions.series=seriesClone;
   myChart=new Highcharts.StockChart(chartOptions);
```

Working example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WMZJ3/)

Comment: thanks, 
when i do that the chart recreated itself but showing no data at all..
it is possible to do that without re creating the chart instance ?

Comment: As you mentioned in Your question about 'update()'http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.update(); it also based on re-instantiation. so it is the only way i think you can do it. it must work please share your code you might be doing something wrong

Comment: function initChart(){
 chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(chartOptions);
}

Comment: I have Edited my Answer you need to add series as well along all options as on draw `series` is set null by the `highcharts`

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like this:

```js
var chart1 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
   chart: {
      zoomType: 'xy', //requried!
      ...
   }
   ...
});

function SwitchToZoomX() {
   chart1.pointer.zoomX = true;
   chart1.pointer.zoomY = false;
   chart1.pointer.zoomHor = true;
   chart1.pointer.zoomVert = false;
}

function SwitchToZoomY() {
   chart1.pointer.zoomY = true;
   chart1.pointer.zoomX = false;
   chart1.pointer.zoomVert = true;
   chart1.pointer.zoomHor = false;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is actually the correct answer. I wonder why it isn't upvoted more, since this question comes up quite often all over the Internet.

Answer (score 6):

With Highcharts v5 you can now do this:

```js
chart1.update({chart: {zoomType: "y"}})
```

The `update` function dynamically updates the chartoptions to imperitively change `zoomType` post render.